# discord.js - How to get the name/id of the bot's voiceChannel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have tested variable = client.voiceChannel but it always returns an undefined variable. So, there is a method to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know all the voice channels where the bot is you can use [`client.voiceConnections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=voiceConnections).

> All active voice connections that have been established, mapped by guild ID

An example could be this:

```
client.voiceConnections.map(voiceConnection => console.log(voiceConnection));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Guild.id then you can pass it to get the exact channel id

```
bot.voiceConnections.get(GuildID).channel.id
```